# Convert a problem o minimizing a function to linear programming problem in standard form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have to **1)** convert a problem o minimizing a function to linear programming problem in standard form. It is something new to me. Can somebody explain it to me?

$$\min(\mathbb{R}^2\ni(x,y)\rightarrow xy \in \mathbb{R})$$
on a set
$$x^2+y^2\le 7$$

**2)** Find that minimum using linear programming in standard form.

Comment: You cannot. The feasible set is a circle (i.e, not LP-representable) and the objective is bilinear.

Comment: Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: About what? It is a circle, and thus not the intersection of finite set of hyperplanes (a polyhedron) which is the only thing you can optimize over in linear programming.